# Bullet speed while running in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame. I'm developing a game in which you figth your enemies, both using guns. It is working well but I have a problem with the player when he's shooting while moving.

I attach the examples:

[image: Shooting quiet]

[image: Shooting while moving]

How can I do that when I shoot while running, the bullets come out with the same frequency?

I have this code for manage it:

```py
if self.keysPushed[K_b]:
            if self.player.timeSinceLastShot > self.player.shootCooldown:
                self.bulletPoolPlayer.shoot((self.player.posX, self.player.posY), self.player.direction)
                self.player.timeSinceLastShot = 0
                self.sonidoDisparo.set_volume(0.5)
                self.sonidoDisparo.play(maxtime=250)
```

I tried to multiply the vector self.player.direction by an scalar but when I did, the sprite wasn't displayed in the correct orientation.

Answer (score 1):

The bullets are actually being shot with the same frequency, but the fact your player is moving causes a similar effect as the Doppler effect.
What you want is pretty obvious, but the 'correct' way to shoot is actually what you get here. Another way is to implement range for bullets,  or check that the last fired bullet is far enough from the player before shooting another one.